# Unable to reinstall GRUB on encrypted filesystem

Tags: ubuntu, grub, ecryptfs

I made a mistake and deleted the contents of my /boot directory, including GRUB (btw this is easy to do, there is no notice that it will make your system unbootable)!

I was going to try to re-copy GRUB into the directory before I rebooted but I forgot, and rebooted, and, no surprise, it wouldn't boot.
I have an encrypted filesystem, and an encrypted home directory.

Now on a liveUSB, trying all kinds of forum advice (without posting myself)....no luck.
I have managed to mount my encrypted drive (yay), but the boot-repair package and grub-repair both throw up errors.
here is my pastebin:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/14875709/

Has anyone run into this situation and can possibly help me?

fdisk:

```
Device       Start       End   Sectors  Size Type   
/dev/sda1     2048   1050623   1048576  512M BIOS boot   
/dev/sda2  1050624   1550335    499712  244M Linux filesystem   
/dev/sda3  1550336 976771071 975220736  465G Linux filesystem   
/dev/sdb1  *      128 3911679 3911552  1.9G  b W95 FAT32
```

Tried the grub-install, update-grub sequence suggested below - it threw up a bunch of warnings of:

```
/run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory  
WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
```

but seemed successful, with grub-install ending:

```
Installation finished. No error reported.
```

and update-grub ending:

```
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration  
done
```

btw I should mention I also (previously) edited `/etc/default/grub` and added

```
GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK=y
```

as that was suggested in a different forum - is that necessary?

Anyway upon reboot, it immediately asks for the encrypted disk passphrase, then seems to accept it, gives me a grub menu, then after going through most of the boot sequence gives me this error (may not be exact, I wrote it down):

```
drm:intel_pipe_config_compare error: mismatch in ips_enabled (expected 1, found 0)
```

It sends me to a busybox emergency shell prompt with the suggestion that I `cat /proc/cmdline` because:

```
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vgroot does not exist
```

However, it does exist, I am able to mount it via liveCD, it is just encrypted.
So I'm stuck again.

**Update:** I tried editing '/etc/lvm/lvm.conf' as advised, now when I reboot I get the grub menu, but then after selecting Ubuntu it goes to the emergency shell again with the same error:

```
drm:intel_pipe_config_compare [i915] ERROR mismatch in ips_enabled (expected 1, found 0)
```

Comment: Could you post the output of `gdisk` `p` `q` or `fdisk` `p` `q` if `gdisk` doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're talking about Ubuntu, I'm going to assume you use that.

To fix, do the following:

- first, ensure you're working on the *installed* system, not the live system. A live image usually has its own root filesystem that makes reinstalling grub harder than it could be. Assuming you mount your installed root filesystem on `/mnt`, you can do this by running the following commands (all as root, so use sudo or something along those lines if needs be):

  ```
  mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev
  mount -t process proc /mnt/proc
  mount -t sysfs sys /mnt/sys
  chroot /mnt
  ```

  This last command starts a shell inside your installed system. Run the next commands in that shell.
- reinstall grub to the MBR: `grub-install --boot-directory=/boot /dev/sda`. This assumes your computer has only one harddisk, or that if it has more, it is set up to boot from `sda`. If that's not the case, adjust as appropriate.
- regenerate the grub menu for good measure: `update-grub`.
- now exit from that shell, and reboot.

Things should work again. If not, please update your question with some more details on how things fail.

**Update**: looks like things still fail due to update-grub wanting to talk to `lvmetad`, which runs in the host system, not the guest. The easiest way to fix that is to (temporarily) disable use of that daemon. To do so, edit `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf`, find the setting that says `use_lvmetad = 1` and set it to `0`. Then run `update-initramfs -u -k all` to regenerate the initramfs.

Comment: thanks - I updated with more info .....hope you or someone has more ideas! I am worried about the data on my encrypted volume :(